# Set text items vertically or horizontally based on text width

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to show a list of buttons either vertically or horizontally and make that decision based on how the text fits in the view.
I need to display the buttons like this: 
[image: Pic image]

but if the width of the text is longer and it needs to move it to a new line, I need to change the orientation and set them vertically, like so:

[image]

The number of items can differ, from 2 to at most 10. How can I know if the text will fit in the horizontally aligned views so that If they don't I can make them align vertically?

Comment: check this https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: hmm, looks interesting but ... I can't seem to see how I'd go about doing what I need in my case.  I've found something but that moves the new item on a new row if it won't fit, but in my case I need to move ALL items to a new row in case at least one doesn't fit. hmm, any ideas ?

Comment: yeah. construct your own layout for it and I just gave flex-box for find the logic.

Comment: Is all this happening as a part of a GridLayout? Because then it makes sense to use the "GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup".

Comment: Did you found answer??

Answer (score 0):

If Parent Layout has more than 4(or)5 view the String value will definitely break into new line,so if u want suggestions Use this if it helps

Make Parent Layout as Linear Layout with default orientation as horizontal in XML

In JAVA code check `String raspuns = "dynamic string";` length

Try this

```
LinearLayout parent_layout = findViewById(R.id.parent);
if(raspuns.length > 7){
   parent_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
}
```

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use `android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout` which is

> An extension of LinearLayout that automatically switches to vertical 
>   orientation when it can't fit its child views horizontally.

Which is being used by Android itself in [abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/HEAD/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml)

---

So the code would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layoutDirection="locale"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@android:id/button3"
        style="?attr/buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Neutral button" />

    <android.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/spacer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@android:id/button2"
        style="?attr/buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Negative button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@android:id/button1"
        style="?attr/buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Positive button" />
</android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
```

Output of this xml is

[image: Stacked button active]

And if text is small for buttons, output for same layout is 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just try like this and it's working fine for me

**Layout**

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**code for Rearrange views**

```
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
    val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
    var viewsWidth = 0;
    for (i in 0..linear.childCount - 1) {
        linear.getChildAt(i).post({
            viewsWidth += linear.getChildAt(i).width
            if (i == linear.childCount - 1) {
                if (width < viewsWidth) {
                    linear.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                    for (k in 0..linear.childCount - 1) {
                        (linear.getChildAt(k) as Button).width = (width - resources.getDimension(R.dimen.spacing_large)).toInt()
                        linear.getChildAt(k).requestLayout()
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And `spacing_large` is sum of `margin_start` and `margin_end`